# keyboardWillShow will only work from the second time on

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, uikeyboard

I have a UITextView that I need to move up when the user focuses on it.

In the simulator I have set up 2 keyboards (English,Greek)

Within `keyboardWillShow` function I change the UITextView's height to be less than the existing one, as in

`self.page_text.frame = CGRectMake(self.page_text.frame.origin.x, self.page_text.frame.origin.y, self.page_text.frame.width, (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as NSValue).CGRectValue().origin.y - 180)`

The problem is that only **each first time** I focus on the text view the keyboard appears but the UITextView's height does not change:

[image: first keyboard appearance]

After that first time, each time I change the keyboard's language the text view behaves as expected.

[image: second time appearance]

Why could this be happening?

The project can be found [here](https://github.com/abinop/Test26001914)

PS: I noticed that if the two keyboards are in the same language (ex US English and UK English), the height **never changes.** How strange is that?